F-Sy-H (fast-syntax-highlighting) highlights some text unreadable on light background?
I use iTerm2 + p10k + F-Sy-H. And as shown in the image below, the text awk "asdf" becomes unreadable.

Is this issue happening because my F-Sy-H theme isn't compatible with a light background? I've tried several themes, but none are ideal. Are there any F-Sy-H themes specifically designed for light backgrounds?
